# Sqlite query to select similar unknown rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

The table is in following format

```
 item | price | quantity
 xyz  |   20  |10
 xyz  |   20  |10
 abc  |   10  |40
 def  |   60  |110
```

I want to select all values which is equivalent to "xyz" in the item column.

Comment: You may try "select * from <tablename> where item = "xyz"

Comment: "xyz"  is just the special case of a problem. I want a generic solution that works for all such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to bundle a combination of columns together, and combine it with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to select only those where there are more than one. Example:

```
sqlite> create table t(item,price,quantity);
sqlite> insert into t select 'xyz',20,10;
sqlite> insert into t select 'xyz',20,10;
sqlite> insert into t select 'abc',10,40;
sqlite> insert into t select 'def',60,110;
sqlite> select *,count(*) from t group by item,price,quantity having count(*) > 1;
xyz|20|10|2
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 1 row for each item then u can use below query

```
select item, sun(price), sum(quantity)
from tablename
group by item
```

if you want to select particluar item then you can use below query

```
select * from tablename where item=??
```

?? could be replace with actual value